# How to UPDATE column with ROW_NUMBER() in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions

I'm having a table like this

```
Create table test1(emp_id decimal(5,0), emp_name varchar(20));

Insert into test1(2015,'XYZ');
Insert into test1(2016,'XYZ2');
```

Now I want to update emp_id to row_number() 
or
add new column into same table like (emp_no integer) to row_number().

can anyone please tell me the query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use UPDATE FROM:

```
UPDATE test1
FROM
 ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY emp_id) AS rn,
     emp_id 
   FROM test1
 ) AS src
SET emp_id = src.rn
WHERE test1.emp_id = src.emp_id -- must be unique column(s)
```

Btw, instead of updating all rows of a table it *might* be better to INSERT/SELECT or MERGE the SELECT into a new table. You *must* do it if there's no unique column, you *should* if `emp_id` is the PI of your table (otherwise performance will be horrible).

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. And I have one more doubt, If I'm having same column emp_id having 'null' value or same value for all rows like 1, what is the query? can you please tell me.

Comment: @VivekHarry: If there are duplicate rows there's no way to update, you need a new table plus Insert/Select. For a single NULL you can add `WHERE test1.emp_id = src.emp_id or (test1.emp_id is null and src.emp_id is null)`

Comment: can you please tell me,how to UPDATE a non unique column into IDENTITY VALUE like (1,2,3,...)

Comment: @VivekHarry: As I already wrote, if there's no unique column combination there's no way to UPDATE, you need to create a new table and INSERT/SELECT the ROW_NUMBER query. Btw, the IDENTITY inserts are not guaranteed to be sequential.

Comment: Thanks again. Can I ADD IDENTITY COLUMN into existing tables, but that tables does not have any UNIQUE INDEX or PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @VivekHarry: You don't need a unique index you need a unique combination of columns. In a relational database every table has a logical Primary Key.

Comment: see my example table above, in that table I have created without having primary key. In that case, how can I achieve. In Teradata, Not all table must have primary key column.

Answer (score 1):

```
Create table test1(
  emp_id decimal(5,0), 
  emp_name varchar(20),
  emp_no INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
         (START WITH 1
          INCREMENT BY 1
         )
);

Insert into test1(2015,'XYZ1',2);
Insert into test1(2016,'XYZ2',2);      
Insert into test1(2015,'XYZ3',null);
Insert into test1(2016,'XYZ4',null);
```

Comment: thank you so much, But I want to UPDATE a non unique column into IDENTITY Value like (1,2,3,..)

Comment: I don't believe identity allows non-unique values. Identity itself can either be updateable (by default clause) or auto-generated (always clause).

Comment: actually in Teradata I can add a identity column into existing table, how can I achieve this ? can any one tell me please?